# Redis Pub/Sub not keeping messages

Tags: redis, queue, publish-subscribe

I'm using Redis Pub/Sub implementation to exchange messages between two projects. I have a few channels subscribing the same queue. When both publisher and subscriber are running, everything goes well. When I have only the publisher working(and a lot of messages are published), I would expect that when the subscriber starts, it would read all the messages that were enqueued previously. But what happens is that Redis does not keep the messages if there is no subscriber. Is there any configuration I could use to keep the messages until a subscriber dequeue them?

Answer (score 2):

Redis currently doesn't behave like an MQTT broker with his "retain" flag.

If the subscription occur after the message has been published, It will be missed for the subscriber and lost forever.